# How to handle wide markdown tables and line-length checks in pre-commit?

Tags: layout, formatting, markdown, pre-commit, linter

### Context

After applying a line length limit of 80 characters on the pre-commit check of `markdown-lint`, I was experiencing some difficulties in including a markdown table that I create with more width than 80 characters.

### Note

I see value in applying the linter to the `README.md` because I quite often forget about the line length while typing the `README.md`. (In essence, the trivial solution: disable the linter or disable `MD013` everywhere, is considered sub-optimal).

### Pre-commit of MarkdownLint

```yaml
- repo: https://github.com/markdownlint/markdownlint
   rev: v0.11.0
   hooks:
     - id: markdownlint
```

## Markdown table example

```
| Algorithm                            | Encoding | Adaptation | Radiation    | Backend                      |
| ------------------------------------ | -------- | ---------- | ------------ | ---------------------------- |
| Minimum Dominating Set Approximation | Sparse   | Redundancy | Neuron Death | - networkx LIF<br>- Lava LIF |
| Some Algorithm Approximation         | Sparse   | Redundancy | Neuron Death | - networkx LIF<br>- Lava LIF |
|                                      |          |            |              |                              |
```

### Approach I

First I tried to include a `ignore MD013` (line length check) in the relevant section of the Markdown table, however, Markdown Lint [does not support such an option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74255575/7437143).

### Approach II

I tried to manually apply the new line breaks to the table, however, that results in additional rows in the table:
[image]

### Question

How can I stay within the 80 lines whilst including a wide markdown table, (without generating new horizontal lines)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try changing your hook to another similar project: [igorshubovych/markdownlint-cli](https://github.com/igorshubovych/markdownlint-cli)

```yaml
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/igorshubovych/markdownlint-cli
    rev: v0.32.2
    hooks:
      - id: markdownlint
        args: ["--fix"]
```

You may include a `.markdownlint.yaml` file in the same directory as your `.pre-commit-config.yaml`. Set the line length rule but ignore it for tables. Like so:

```yaml
# Default state for all rules
default: true

# MD013/line-length - Line length
MD013:
  line_length: 80
  tables: false
```

Check the [`.markdownlint.yaml` schema](https://github.com/DavidAnson/markdownlint/blob/main/schema/.markdownlint.yaml) for other configuration options.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Your suggestions resolved the issue after copying your files and running `pre-commit install`.

Answer (score 2):

I want to mention that something similar to @Gabriel's answer should work for you if (like me) you don't have a `pre-commit-config.yaml` file.

just make a `.markdownlint.json` file at the root of your project, with the following content:

```
{
  "MD013": {
      "line_length": 80,
      "code_block_line_length": 120,
      "tables": false
    }
  
}
```

You could now set your line length to be whatever you prefer; alternatively, you could set the line checking to be false for tables.